# 404 error on Post Request to submit a file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded my script to upload a file and copying the same request but I am getting 404 error when I am manually running the request to upload a file
Note: I have already added my file in bin folder
Here are the work which I have added

[The headers I am setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDK98.png)

[Http request details I am adding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfdC4.png)

[Sampler Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBUqk.png)

[My Request Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4CCE.png)

I have tried adding the file in my bin folder
I have tried uploading the file through file upload component but the HTML does not contact name attribute that's why I cant use name attribute

I am expecting to successfully upload the file

Answer (score 0):

1. As per [HTTP Status 404 documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404):

   > The HTTP `404 Not Found` response status code indicates that the server cannot find the requested resource. Links that lead to a 404 page are often called broken or dead links and can be subject to [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).
   >
   > A 404 status code only indicates that the resource is missing: not whether the absence is temporary or permanent. If a resource is permanently removed, use the [410](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410) (Gone) status instead.

   So first of all double check that your URL is correct
2. Most probably your way of uploading the file is not correct, I think you you need to:

   - remove Content-Length and Content-Type headers from the HTTP Header Manager
   - Tick `Use multipart-form/data` box in the HTTP Request sampler
   - Move the `file` parameter to Files Upload tab of the HTTP Request sampler

     [image]

If cannot figure out the proper configuration for the file upload you can just record it using your browser (or other application) and JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html). More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload & Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Comment: I did try adding the same configuration which is user by the recorder still I am getting 400 error